# jQuery - fadeTo() - how do i make it fade more and more everytime the event is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write a script that will at first fade the picture to 80%, then 60%, etc.. all the way down to 1%, but when i call the event (.click) all i get is a one time deal where it goes to my set opacity.  how can i keep it going?  thanks in advance.  here is my code:

```
<html>
<center><img 

src="image1.jpg"
id="1"><br><img src="image2.jpg" 

width="500" height-"500" id="2" ></img></center>

</html>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#2").click(function() {

      $("#1").fadeTo(500,.3);


   });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of a variable that increases every time it's being called:

```
var x=1;
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("#2").click(function() {
      if((x*.75)>(.01)){
      x=x*.75; //whatever desired pattern       
      }
      $("#1").fadeTo(500, x);
   });

});
```

Comment: Adding to the opacity is the opposite of what is wanted I believe.

Comment: thanks so much for the asnwer, will accept soon, was wondering though, is there anyway to keep x from fading the entire way out?  like if i want it to go to .1 and stop?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question accordingly, it decreases by 25% as long as it is above 1% then it will stop. Note that you can change the pattern of the decrease by changing the `.75` value.

Comment: This is not decreasing lineer as he described in the question. It takes lots of clicks to totally fade away, instead of 5 clicks...

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#2").click(function() {
      if($("#1").css("opacity")>.2) {
        $("#1").fadeTo(500,$("#1").css("opacity")-.2);
      } else {
        $("#1").fadeTo(500, .01);
        $("#2").unbind("click");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: This won't stop at 1% as described per his requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Either keep track of the current opacity via a variable, or get the current opacity via jquery like so
    var opacity = $('elemFoo').css('opacity');

then decrement the opacityby the desired level.

```
var opacity= $('elemFoo').css('opacity');
if(opacity > 0.2){
  $('elemFoo').faceTo(opacity - 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var opacity = 1;

$("#2").click(function() {
    opacity = opacity * .75;

    $("#1").fadeTo(500, opacity);
});
```

This will decrease the opacity by 25% of the current opacity each click.  You can modify the calculation to adjust how much extra it fades each time.

http://jsfiddle.net/MPd3x/1/